# Change discord.py embed field position

Tags: discord.py

Is it possible to change the position of an embed field in discord.py?
Here is my more detailed problem:
I have an embed, but I have to make it modular, which means that with a command we can either add a field or delete one. The delete command works and the add command works, but now I need to be able to change the position of the field to be the same as the position of the role (because each field corresponds to a role).
How can I do that?

Comment: Before adding all the fields to the embed, sort the data in the same order as your roles, and THEN add the fields.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do right now, thanks for your answer !
I have a list of roles, and thanks to the sorted function I can sort the list but i need to do it to the role.position and not to the role itself which is in my list, I'm trying to think about how to do it ><

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `sorted` has a `key` argument where you can pass a function that returns the value to be sorted on. In your case, something like `key=lambda role: role.position`.

Comment: i found the solution but i'll send my codes in the original question

Comment: Why would you post the solution in the question? It should be in an answer instead. That's what answers are for.

Comment: i just wanted to post it here idk

Comment: Also by posting your code in the question you leaked your bot token. Generate a new one.

Comment: omfg ye i didnt see that... thanks i generated a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't edit embed field's position, but we can try to add every fields in the good ordor so we don't have to edit the field's position !

Here are my codes (working):

```py
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime


intents = discord.Intents.all()


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!1789", help_command = None, intents=intents)

async def get_hour():
    now = ""
    now = datetime.now()
    hour = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    return hour

async def role_members_mention(role: discord.Role, emoji):
    role_str = ""
    if len(role.members):
        for member in role.members:
            role_str += f"**|** {emoji} **➜** {member.mention}\n"
            role_str[:-1]
    
    return role_str

async def soon(role, emoji, max):
    soon = f"**|** {emoji} **➜ Soon**\n" * (int(max[role.name].replace("/", "")) - len(role.members))
    soon[:-1]

    return soon

async def get_all_roles():
    guild = bot.get_guild(966749409314504774)
    global ceo_aceo_roles_dict
    ceo_aceo_roles_dict = {}
    ceo = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id = 966749523949023262)
    aceo = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id = 992137775883243530)
    global all_roles_dict
    all_roles_dict = {}
    all_roles_dict[ceo.position] = ceo
    all_roles_dict[aceo.position] = aceo
    ceo_aceo_roles_dict[ceo.position] = ceo
    ceo_aceo_roles_dict[aceo.position] = aceo

async def update_effective():
    ceo_aceo = ""
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "**E͟͟͟F͟͟͟F͟͟͟E͟͟͟C͟͟͟T͟͟͟I͟͟͟F͟͟͟ S͟͟͟T͟͟͟A͟͟͟F͟͟͟F͟͟͟**.  <:3446blurplecertifiedmoderator:1001403463214825542>", description = "", color = 0x000000)
    max = {}
    total = {}
    effectif_staff_emojis = ["<:adcrown:1001400557073866762>", "<:bluesettings:1001472768161894532>", "<:diplome:1001472522811883621>", "<:5961blurpleemployee:1001403806828994570>"]
    roles_staff_emojis = ["<:5961blurpleemployee:1001403806828994570>", "<:Dev:1001412860091580487>", "<:direction:1001476149051924591>", "<:bluevoicechannel:1001473637091659836", "<:direction:1001476149051924591>", "<:spideyn7:996331019735158864>", "<:logo_twitch:1005196891010629702>"]
    all_roles = sorted(all_roles_dict)
    ceo_aceo_roles = sorted(ceo_aceo_roles_dict)
    all_roles.reverse()
    ceo_aceo_roles.reverse()
    x = -1
    for role in all_roles:
        x += 1
        all_roles[x] = all_roles_dict[role]
    x = -1
    for role in ceo_aceo_roles:
        x += 1
        ceo_aceo_roles[x] = ceo_aceo_roles_dict[role]


    for role in all_roles:
        number = 0
        for car in role.name:
            if car == "‎":
                number += 1
        max[role.name] = "/" + str(number)
        if len(role.members) >= int(max[role.name].replace("/", "")):
            total[role.name] = f" **{str(len(role.members))} {max[role.name]}**"
        else:
            total[role.name] = f" **{str(len(role.members))} {max[role.name]}**"

    message = await (await get_effective_staff_channel()).fetch_message(1059250505689337998)
    for role in ceo_aceo_roles:
        ceo_aceo += f"{role.mention} {total[role.name]}\n{await role_members_mention(role, effectif_staff_emojis[0])}{await soon(role, effectif_staff_emojis[0], max)}\n\n"

    embed.add_field(name = "**C.E.O & A.C.E.O** <:adcrown:1001400557073866762>", value = ceo_aceo, inline = False)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1001404772496187392/1059246720669733014/Picsart_22-10-19_21-20-35-971.jpg?width=1326&height=529")
    embed.set_image(url = "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1001404772496187392/1059246720875241542/Picsart_22-10-13_21-14-41-363.jpg?width=618&height=618")

    await message.edit(embed = embed)

async def delete_messages(ctx, number_of_message_to_delete = 1, time_to_wait = 0):
    await asyncio.sleep(time_to_wait)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=number_of_message_to_delete)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"[{await get_hour()}] Ready !\n        Username: {bot.user.name}\n----------------------------------------------------")
    await get_all_roles()
    await update_effective()
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(600)
        await update_effective()

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def addeffectifstaff(ctx, role: discord.Role, number = 1):
    await delete_messages(ctx)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id = role.id)
    if role in all_roles_dict.values():
        await ctx.send("Désolé mais ce rôle est déjà dans l'effectif.")
    else:
        ceo_aceo_roles_dict[role.position] = role
        all_roles_dict[role.position] = role
        await update_effective()
        await ctx.send(f"Bien ! Le rôle {role.name} a été ajouté à l'effectif !")
    await delete_messages(ctx, 1, 3)
    print(f'[{await get_hour()}] {ctx.author.name} used the command "addeffectifstaff" to make me add the role "{role.name}" to the effective message.')

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def deleffectif(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    await delete_messages(ctx)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id = role.id)
    if not role in all_roles_dict.values():
        await ctx.send("Désolé mais ce rôle n'est déjà pas dans l'effectif.")
    else:
        ceo_aceo_roles_dict.pop(role.position)
        all_roles_dict.pop(role.position)
        await update_effective()
        await ctx.send(f"Bien ! Le rôle {role.name} a été supprimé de l'effectif !")
    await delete_messages(ctx, 1, 3)
    print(f'[{await get_hour()}] {ctx.author.name} used the command "deleffectif" to make me remove the role "{role.name}" to the effective message.')

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: there is no answer to my question, what i wanted was just impossible, that's it